# How do I adjust the margins and text width of only a couple of pages in a whole report?

Tags: table-of-contents

I would like to adjust the margins and text width locally on a separate part of a long report. The "List of Figures" section doesn't look good right now, because the figure number and text float together, see attached figure!

I've tried a couple of things and searched quite long without success.

Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards,
Gustaf[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: You are already doing something since the figure number uses a different font.  In any case, you probably need to modify `\l@figure`, which specifies the margins used.

Comment: @JohnKormylo that is more likely to just be the box where the figure number is is. That is normally configurable on its own, no need to mess with `\l@figure` which mich be daunting for novice users.

Answer (score 1):

The space allocated to the figure number can be increased from the default `2.3em` (`book`, `report` and `article` class).

[image: a]

```
    \documentclass{report}

%**************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@figure{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{3em}} % default \@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}
\makeatother
%****************************************

\begin{document}
    
    \listoffigures
    
    \appendix
    
    \chapter{Figures}
    \setcounter{figure}{174}% only for this example
    \begin{figure}
         figure 175
        \caption{A figure}
    \end{figure}
    
    
    \begin{figure}
     figure 176
        \caption{Another figure}
    \end{figure}

    \begin{figure}      
    figure 177
    \caption{And another}
\end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```

**Option** The `tocloft` package provides many commands to configure ToC, Lof, and LoT based on specific requirements. In this case it is enough

```
\usepackage{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftfignumwidth}{3.0em}
```